# python: transform ranges to continuous distribution using pandas(bedgraph to sgr)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I would like to find an efficient way to transform(and in general, handle) data like here(bedgraph):

`Mito    186     205     7.0
Mito    479     497     5.0
Mito    992     1011    1.0`

to following structure(sgr):

`Mito    187     7.0
Mito    188     7.0
Mito    189     7.0
Mito    190     7.0
Mito    191     7.0
Mito    192     7.0
...`

bedgraph file are ~ 2x3MB
sgr are ~ 2*20MB
I will work with multiple files like that.
What would be faster, to read bedgraph file and transform to sgr or to read much larger sgr file?

Comment: Can you show your df ? Included columns name

Comment: there is no concrete names, you can use: ["chr","start","stop","hits"] for bedgraph and ["chr","position","hits"] for sgr. Dataframe would be quite large... 12 mln lines for sgr file